# How to open a window from another storyboard?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, storyboard, xib

[Click here for the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3ru2.png)

I have a main storyboard where I have 3 buttons that have to be connected with 3 different windows found in 3 different xib files.

How to do this?

Comment: A storyboard reference, perhaps?  It's not entirely clear what you're asking.  Connected how?

Comment: I edited the post with a picture so you can understand

Answer (score 0):

You should give more information on what you have tried and how far you are but I think this should work.

let mainViewController = MainViewController(nibName: "MainViewController", bundle: nil)

nibName is the name you gave your .xib file

Comment: I edited the post with a picture so you can understand